# Solr HTTP 400 Error Bad Request on search

Tags: apache, http, solr, plone

I currently get the following error when dispatching a query.

```
 Module collective.solr.search, line 94, in search
  Module collective.solr.solr, line 266, in search
  Module collective.solr.solr, line 127, in doPost
  Module collective.solr.solr, line 116, in __errcheck
SolrException: HTTP code=400, reason=Bad Request
```

I also get an 'HTTP code-400, reason=Bad Request' error when I try to upload a file or create a new page.

To me it seems there is a problem with the server connection, although everything else is running just fine. Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong here?

The error log (after a query):

```
4/21/2016, 3:38:27 PM | ERROR | ShowFileRequestHandler | Can not find: admin-extra.html [/opt/plone/Plone/zeocluster/parts/solr-instance/solr/plone/conf/admin-extra.html]
4/21/2016, 3:40:26 PM | ERROR | SolrCore | org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: no field name specified in query and no default specified via 'df' param
```

Comment: Did you checked the Solr error log?

Comment: I edited my question!

Comment: For what I read so far the admin-extra.html is just a common error in Solr with no further effect.